# [fat-aar][debug]Can not resove :kotlinx-coroutines-core

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I use the kezong fat-aar plugin (from https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android) in order to create an aar artefact including a NDK based project and some other libraries.
I use a lot of kotlin code, so I need kotlinx-coroutines-core to be included in my final aar artefact.

I tried that configuration:

dependencies {
implementation project(':mysubproject')
embed project(path: ':mysubproject', configuration: 'default')
embed 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0'
embed "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
}

All is working well for "mysubproject" and kotlin-reflect, but it's not working for kotlinx-coroutines-core.
I got this message when I sync gradle:

[fat-aar][debug]Can not resove :kotlinx-coroutines-core
[fat-aar][release]Can not resove :kotlinx-coroutines-core

Do you know how I can embed this dependency ? Maybe I am doing something wrong...
Notice, than if I don't put
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0'
in my final app using my artefact, i crashes.

Build Environment

```
Operating System: MacOS 12.1
Gradle Plugin Version: 7.2
Gradle Version: 7.1.1
Fat-aar Version: 1.3.6
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71496817/create-one-aar-from-multi-module-library-in-android/76512441#76512441

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
fataar {
    /**
     * If transitive is true, local jar module and remote library's dependencies will be embed. (local aar module does not support)
     * If transitive is false, just embed first level dependency
     * Default value is false
     * @since 1.3.0
     */
    transitive = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly, I 've already tried that and it does not seem to work better. The only way I found is to use implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0" in my arr project, and to re-implement the same line in final project : implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0" .

Comment: Could I see the dependencies in your arr file? I can download the coroutines even the console log output the same you:

[fat-aar][debug]Can not resove :kotlinx-coroutines-core [fat-aar][release]

Comment: If not, you can download the jar/aar file. Then make it add the module and embed it