# Create one aar from multi module library in android

Tags: android, gradle

I have the following modules in my aaplication

Module

```
-app

-library_1 

-library_2
```

the module `library_1` 'has dependecy of `library_2` 
build gradle library_1

```
dependencies {
api project(":library_2")
}
```

When I build the project I get the aar which I put in my app module

```
dependencies {
implementation files('libs/library_1-debug.aar')
}
```

Now when I run my app I get the exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/dinklo/library_2/LibraryB`

The class `LibraryB` is defined in `library_2` and being called from `library_1`

I am looking for a solution where I can get a single aar file for all the modules I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using third party library [Fat-aar](https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android)

In root build gradle

```
 classpath 'com.github.kezong:fat-aar:1.3.8'
```

In your library module

```
apply plugin: 'com.kezong.fat-aar'

dependencies{
embed project(path: ':lib-2', configuration: 'default')}
```

I have added a sample project on github will be useful for others

[Fat-arr Sample - Github](https://github.com/wishygupta/FatArrSample)

Comment: If you share a working example in your GitHub page and share the link, that would be great. I and many other devs would appreciate your effort. I tried to do a sample app but it does not work.

Comment: @oiyio Sorry for the late response. I have added the github link for sample app you may refer it. Let me know if you face any trouble

Comment: @WISHYCan you pls guide how can I do maven publish on it?. Am finding it difficult to generate the pom file

Comment: @Bytecode you can refer this article https://proandroiddev.com/android-maven-publish-for-your-libraries-b76ad47677df

Answer (score 1):

Since kezong fat aar is not maintained anymore and does not work with gradle 8, I did a fix using bash.
I don't use any plugin.
I decompress aar archives and copy jni folder into decompressed final arr.
Then I decompress also classes.jar and copy content into my final decompressed classes.jar in arr final package.
This seems to work great !
You just have to use unzip and zip command in order to decompress and compress aar and jar. I works easily because I don't have any resource in my aar dependencies.

```
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Do kezong aar plugin job -- integrate dependency into aar package
 
 # decompress dependency aar 
 unzip $VM_AAR_FOLDER/dependency.aar -d $VM_AAR_FOLDER/dependency
 
 # decompress dependency classes.jar
 unzip $VM_AAR_FOLDER/dependency/classes.jar -d $VM_AAR_FOLDER/dependency/classes
 
 
 # decompress target aar file
 unzip $VME_SDK_BUILD_PACKAGE/target.aar -d $VME_SDK_BUILD_PACKAGE/target
 
 # decompress target.jar file
 unzip $VME_SDK_BUILD_PACKAGE/target/classes.jar -d $VME_SDK_BUILD_PACKAGE/target/classes
 
 # copy dependency classes into decompressed target classes folder
 cp -r $VM_AAR_FOLDER/dependency/classes/android $VME_SDK_BUILD_PACKAGE/target/classes/
 cp -r $VM_AAR_FOLDER/dependency/classes/com/company/dependency $VME_SDK_BUILD_PACKAGE/target/classes/com/company/
 
 # copy jni dependency Files into decompressed target folder
 cp -r $VM_AAR_FOLDER/dependency/jni $VME_SDK_BUILD_PACKAGE/target/
 
 # recreate classes.jar in target
 cd $VME_SDK_BUILD_PACKAGE/target/classes/
 rm -Rf ../classes.jar
 zip -r ../classes.jar *
 cd ..
 rm -Rf classes
 
 
 # recreate aar for target
 cd $VME_SDK_BUILD_PACKAGE/target/
 rm -Rf ../target.aar
 zip -r ../target.aar *
 cd ..
 rm -Rf target
```